# Why is transient performance of voltage mode buck affected by bandwidth?

Tags: buck

For voltage-mode controlled buck converters, we often hear that they have poor transient performance under load steps as the bandwidth is usually limited.

I don't understand this. Bandwidth as I recall was for the small-signal performance (over freq). **But when you apply a load step, isn't that inherently a large signal?** Why don't we use slew rate instead?

EDIT: Some clarification.
Bandwidth (3dB bandwidth) is usually defined for a loop for small-signal only. In several books, they mention that to improve the transient response (mainly rise time) of a buck control loop to respond faster to a load step, you must increase the bandwidth of the loop.

My confusion is regarding the load step. If a large load step is applied, that will be a large signal input to the loop. Bandwidth is only defined for small-signal. So why does increasing the bandwidth improve transient response for a large load step?

Comment: A step has frequencies up to infinity. Also, a buck regulator is essentially an LC lowpass filter for converting PWM to DC. If you apply a sudden load, there is a sudden increase in DC output current, and it takes time of multiple PWM cycles to increase the average DC current in the inductor to the level required by the load. Can these ideas be expanded to an answer?

Comment: "*Why don't we use slew rate instead?*" What do you mean by "use"? Use as a metric? Or use as a way to improve transient response? Because you don't get to pick whether the system uses a slew rate and bandwidth.

Comment: @DkNguyen I mean, if you are applying a large signal step, the error amplifier in the voltage mode control will no longer behave as a first order system, it will slew. So for large signals, it makes more sense to consider the max slew rate of the error amplifier instead of the BW of the loop which is only applicable for small signal.

Comment: So a metric then. Okay.

Comment: Yeah, really this is a question about when does small-signal turn into large-signal and whether or not small signal BW is a good enough indication about large signal transient performance.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question to make that more clear. Some (all?) people seem to be interpreting the question differently. Maybe you want to ask instead why slew rate isn't used to characterize transient performance. However, it could just be a language thing for why people say bandwidth in this case, not a datasheet thing.

Comment: Bringing up slew rate seems contradictory, as it is traditionally defined as a nonlinear behavior, and thus a large-signal aspect, not small. The question seems to be asking about small, but clarification is indeed welcome.

Comment: I looked at the slew-rate effect in my [APEC 2015](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202015.pdf) seminar and how it can affect the response.

Answer (score 7):

In a buck converter or any other switching structure, the transient response is dictated by the small-signal closed-loop output impedance, \$Z_{out}\$. You are correct, this is a small-signal low-level approximation and it no longer holds in presence of large steps and wide duty ratio variations. When the op-amp starts slewing, the system becomes nonlinear and requires different analysis tools. The small-signal response is used to predict, most of the time, the transient response.

In a converter, the response is mainly dominated by the output capacitor in presence of a large output steps. This is because even if the error voltage would immediately respond by increasing the control variable - assume an infinite bandwidth - then the current in the inductor could not rise at a pace faster than what the volt-seconds permit (\$\frac{V}{L}\$). The output capacitor is made of a capacitance value and two parasitics such as the equivalent series resistance (ESR) and an equivalent series inductance, the ESL:

[image]

This image is excerpted from my [seminar](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf) *The Dark Side of Loop Control Theory* that I taught in 2012 at an APEC event and available for download from my [webpage](http://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm). You can see that the undershoot is made of three component: ESL (depends on the step current slope), the ESR (depends on the step current amplitude) and the capacitance whose depth depends on crossover frequency - the bandwidth of the closed-loop system - and, marginally, the phase margin.

It is possible to show that the transient response, mainly the undershoot, can be reduced by increasing the crossover frequency. By doing so, the capacitance contribution diminishes and shrinks to a point where only the ESR step remains. Should you push crossover farther, it would not help. Therefore, neglecting the ESR contribution as a first approximation or considering that the capacitive impedance dominates the output impedance at crossover (\$r_C<<|\frac{1}{j\omega_cC_{out}}|)\$, then the undershoot can be approximated to what the below picture illustrates (see my 2021 seminar *[Designing Compensators for the Control of Switching Power Supplies](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202021.pdf)*):

[image]

Depending on the control mode, voltage- or current-mode control, there can be different formulas but experience shows that this expression gives excellent results. Actually, it is not there to predict the drop at the µV level but more to realize how crossover affects the response and how pushing \$f_c\$ for the sake of the performance is vain: when the response hits the ESR step, this is the best you can get, at least in this simple case. Practically speaking, determine the output capacitor you need for output ripple, rms, voltage etc. and then adjust \$f_c\$ to approach the transient requirements predicted by the formula. Increasing this crossover frequency may uselessly increase the susceptibility to noise without improving transient.

The demonstration of the formula is carried in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3280631_Critical_Bandwidth_for_the_Load_Transient_Response_of_Voltage_Regulator_Modules) and a different view is given [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4334912_Revisiting_the_closed_loop_response_of_PWM_converters_controlled_by_voltage_feedback).

Comment: Excellent answer. So, really the small-signal BW is just an approximation to how the system will be behave when subjected to large load steps? Most books I have read, they always mention that to increase transient performance when subjected to a load step, you need to increase loop BW. So I guess, they are always approximating or assuming a small-signal load step?

Comment: The other way to assess the transient response is to multiply the closed-loop output impedance (which can be a system of high order depending on the compensator) by a current step in Laplace and compute the inverse Laplace transform. But here also, a linear system is assumed and the maths are quite heavy for that. And I doubt people go for a nonlinear analysis as it is much faster to build or simulate the compensated closed-loop converter. Keep in mind that for high-speed dc-dc for motherboards, the ESL dominates the response because of the extreme di/dt there and the formula no longer holds.

Answer (score 0):

What is the transient performance stepping over?  The output filter, primarily.

Until the controller can respond (read: phase/time delay due to compensation components, or on the order of its cutoff frequency aka bandwidth), the output is at the mercy of the LC filter.

So the peak (read: voltage sags/overshoots then rebounds, by up to some peak amount, within the duration of the transient) is essentially \$V_\textrm{pk} = I_\textrm{step} \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$.  Or a bit less, hopefully, due to dampening, but it may also be more due to ESR.  Note that ESR causes an additional penalty of \$I_\textrm{step} R_\textrm{ESR}\$, approximately summed on top of the LC response.

A voltage-mode converter must use extra-large components to achieve the same peak voltage step response.  The design is limited by \$L\$ first: it must be large enough to get ripple current acceptably low (usually limited by core loss, as powdered-iron chokes are popular for voltage-mode controls).  Then \$C\$ must be large enough to meet AC regulation (i.e., Vpk within some percentage of Vout), and selected for ESR suitable to compensate the control (while also not being too large to fail regulation again).  Usually, some large electrolytics are used.  Finally, the control loop must roll off somewhere below \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$, else the loop phase shift is too high and peaking or oscillation results (needless to say, violating the AC regulation spec).

Whereas a current-mode converter can respond sooner, having loop bandwidth comparable or greater than \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$, and so less L and C is necessary for the same transient response.  Operation can also be more stable in DCM (discontinuous conduction mode), such as with peak current mode control.  Which means, to put it another way: the control responds during the transient, rather than making up the difference gradually over time.

And we're often quite concerned with the size and cost of these components, so we call that a performance difference.

Comment: I still have some doubts. The bandwidth of the system tells us of the small signal transient response of the system. If we apply a large load current step at the output of the buck, there will be a large voltage undershoot. This is a large signal change now. So the bandwidth should not be able to predict how the loop will react since bandwidth is for small signal only.

Comment: @AlfroJang80  But I have not made any assumptions regarding signal level here. In fact it's better without, as that avoids crossing between DCM/CCM.  The load step can be arbitrarily small, assuming you still have adequate SNR to read it!